# react-emotion's CSS not present in DOM

Tags: reactjs, puppeteer, emotion

I use `react-emotion` to style some of my React components. I try to prerender my page with a server-side started Chromium instance (`puppeteer`), fetching the freshly build website and retrieve it's HTML as a string, to save it in it's own, dedicated HTML file.

However, every CSS generated by `react-emotion` doesn't get fetched. I've looked up the HTML by myself (using a real Chrome instance) and it's just not present. But the components are all styled correctly. While using the DevTools to look at the style definitions, I can see that every style definition is displayed in italic. What does that mean?

Is there any way to "render" the CSS right into the DOM via a style element?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's currently a problem with Chrome. Emotion uses some kind of Chrome magic, so it doesn't need to render it's CSS to the DOM. You can call this little piece of code, before any emotion is used, to force the DOM rendering (loss of performance).

```
import { sheet } from 'emotion';

sheet.speedy(false);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, myMountPoint);
```

Comment: How can you do this with @emotion v10?

Comment: I don't use v10 yet. :(

Comment: Can you explain which trick emotion do to hide the CSS content from the DOM when doing inspect?

Answer (score 3):

For emotion v11,

```
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react";
import createCache from "@emotion/cache";

// if you are using mui v5
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

const emotionCache = createCache({
  key: "emotion-cache-no-speedy",
  speedy: false,
});

const theme = createTheme();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
        <div>Your app here</div>
      </CacheProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set up `extractStatic` in [`babel-plugin-emotion`](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-emotion).

> Static Extraction:
>
> Generated CSS that is eligible for extraction can
>   be moved to an external css file.

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "emotion",
      {
        "extractStatic": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's semi-working, but I've read about it in emotions docs and seems to be not recommended. Do you have experience with it?

Comment: "If you want to use dynamic values you must use css variables." -> seems to be my problem. :/

Comment: That option has unfortunately been removed, read about the motivation here: https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/blob/master/docs/extract-static.mdx

Answer (score 0):

I wrestled with this problem for a long time. I ended putting the following inside my Puppeteer script, which takes the CSSOM from the browser and injects it as css at the end of the head.

```
// ... truncated puppeteer launch, config etc .... 

let injectStyles = true; // In my code, this is a fun. arg.
let source = await page.content();

// If inject styles, ie, write CSS from the CSSOM
if(injectStyles) {

    // Extract the Styles from the CSSOM
    const css = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const styles = [];
        const styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
        for (const styleSheet of styleSheets) {
            if (styleSheet.cssRules) {
                for (const rule of styleSheet.cssRules) {
                    styles.push(rule.cssText);
                }
            }
        }
        return styles.join('\n');
    });

    // Inject Styles at very end of head
    source = source.replace(
        '</head>',
        `<style>${css}</style></head>`
    ) 
}

// .... continue, do something with source
```